# Allow users to upload to my company one drive folder

Tags: laravel, file, upload, onedrive

I am looking for an example to allow users to upload to my company's one drive folder directly from our website which is using laravel and php, I'd like to make it to where each client has their own folder in which only the client and us can collaborate on within our website. We would like it to where they wouldnt have to have a Microsoft account to do this. Is this possible? and where can I find some examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own specific Laravel [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) in which you will checked user for presence Microsoft accaunt.

Little more info about Laravel Middleware with good example  [Understanding Laravel Middleware](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-laravel-middleware)